# ASP.NET: Tracking dynamic subdomaiins

Tags: asp.net

My company wants to mail out postcards asking the recipient to visit a website for add'l information.  The url on the postcard will contain a unique subdomain, for tracking purposes.

So for example, John Smith's url will look like johnsmith.mysite.com.  Amy Johnson's postcard url will be amyjohnson.mysite.com, etc.

So, 2 questions.  One, can url's be setup in this fashion?  We would be sending thousands of unique postcards, so manually setting up subdomain's on our web host's admin section isn't realistic.  And two, how in asp.net, could I capture just the subdomain?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just do `mysite.com/johnsmith` instead of `johnsmith.mysite.com`? Why does it need to be a sub domain?

Comment: It would but someone within my company believes a personalized sub domain is cleaner looking & will lead to more conversions.  So I need to research if this approach is even doable.  If not, we'll resort to the method you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took an alternate approach to resolving my problem.  Instead of trying to handle this entirely programatically, I created a "wildcard DNS" on my domain with my web host (GoDaddy).  There's some info for it [at this link.](https://www.godaddy.com/help/setting-up-wildcard-dns-3301)

Once my domain was setup to allow wildcard subdomains, I was able to go into my code, and use the following, which allows me to extract the name of the subdomain:

```
Uri url = new Uri(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
string subDomain = GetSubDomain(url);
```

And...

```
public string GetSubDomain(Uri url)
    {
        if (url.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Dns)
        {
            var host = url.Host;
            if (host.Split('.').Length > 2)
            {
                var lastIndex = host.LastIndexOf(".");
                var index = host.LastIndexOf(".", lastIndex - 1);
                return host.Substring(0, index);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```